# Binary string to byte[] in C++?

Tags: c++, string, qt, byte

I'm using QString in Qt actually. So if there's a straightforward function please tell me:)

What I'm thinking of doing is storing a binary string into a file byte by byte:

```
QString code = "0110010101010100111010 /*...still lots of 0s & 1s here..*/";
ofstream out(/*...init the out file here...*/);
for(; code.length() / 8 > 0; code.remove(0, 8))    //a byte is 8 bits
{
    BYTE b = QStringToByte(/*...the first 8 bits of the code left...*/);
    out.write((char *)(&b), 1);
}
/*...deal with the rest less than 8 bits here...*/
```

How should I write my QStringToByte() function?

```
BYTE QStringToByte(QString s)    //s is 8 bits
{
    //?????
}
```

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you come by a "binary string" in the first place?

Comment: And did you want to save those `1`s and `0`s as _bits_ or _bytes_?  Your thought process isn't clear here.

Comment: @RussellBorogove It is an int array encoded with Huffman. So I've first stored the Huffman frequency table and then I want to save this code.

Comment: @MooingDuck I want to save them as BYTE. For the binary string I provided, I would first like to save "01100101" as a byte, and then "01010100" as the next byte, and so on

Comment: Ah. You are modeling a stream of bits with a stream of ASCII characters. Your life will be better if you write a class or a set of functions to model a stream of bits with a stream of bits packed into an array of bytes or integers.

Comment: I don't know where `BYTE` is defined but Qt provides `quint8` which is guaranteed to be that size across all platforms supported by Qt. i.e. more portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QString has a nice [toInt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/3.3/qstring.html#toInt) method, that optionally takes the base as a parameter (in your case base 2). Just strip 8 characters to form a new QString, and do `str.toInt( &somebool, 2 )`.

With no error checking it would be probably:

```
BYTE QStringToByte(QString s)    //s is 8 bits
{
  bool ok;
  return (BYTE)(s.left( 8 ).toInt( &ok, 2 ));
}
```

(don't take my word for it though, never wrote a line in Qt in my life)

Comment: Your method works well enough. Thanks! And don't be that pessimistic:)

Answer (score 0):

You may try `boost::dynamic_bitset` to write bits to a file.

```
void write_to_file( std::ofstream& fp, const boost::dynamic_bitset<boost::uint8_t>& bits )
{
     std::ostream_iterator<boost::uint8_t> osit(fp);
     boost::to_block_range(bits, osit);
}
```

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz "...and now you have two problems."

Comment: @Russel, at least not a ProblemFactory :P